# Wordpress built-in compression of images? How well does it compare to Photoshop or Shortpixel?

Tags: plugins, images, seo, compression

I think the quiestion is pretty straight forward.

I have around 5000 images I want to upload. I need to compress them somehow, but how?!

Photoshop compression
or
use the built-in compression of new wordpress versions.

Like does Photoshop do anything better? Because the only thing I can see in Photoshop is basically the % of compression for jpg. It also offers a preview of the image but I don't really care nor need that for these types of images. I would do it in a batch either way.

So yeah, really? What is the difference and what would be beneficial in using the Photoshop compression or Shortpixel compression?

Comment: have you tried all 3 with a test image and compared them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only true answer to this is to try an image in all three and compare the results. Photoshop and Shortpixel are off topic here, but also change with time so any answer would be out of date. You will need to look at non-WordPress resources to figure out the best optimisation strategy.

**As for WordPress, it does nothing special as far as compression is concerned.** You can adjust the quality % value of resized images when they're JPEGs but that's it. *WordPress does not modify the uploaded image to try and optimise it.*

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: if this answers your question please consider marking it as the correct answer using the tick under the voting buttons

Comment: oh I will do it sir because you went through the trouble of answering me! Thank you so much!!! Yes this cuts to the point and gives me the insight where further to look for information. I was not rude because I did not leave "correct answer" markings. I just did not know. Often people on this stack exchange give vague answers and always say "it depends" even in some very clear situations in the fields where I am expert such as medicine and math. you are not one of those. You answered my question down to the point but either way thank you so much . I am new to stack exchange and was frustrated

Comment: I was frustrated at the beginning because I did not know how to use it, so I asked questions in wrong forums. But then when I finally learned how to ask a question and where, people often gave answers with so much caution as if something horrible will happen if they do not tell me the best option. All I am trying to do is avoid HORRIBLE mistakes. No matter what kind of solution they suggest me in web development, it will be better than a total noob solution. But they often pursue the  best option idealists and answer with "it depends" "we need to benchmark it to make sure"

Comment: I just gave you the correct answer Tom but I still can not give it a vote as well because it says " don't have good reputation yet"

Comment: no offence taken, some people aren't aware of the tick so it helps to point it out :) Afterall it gives you reputation too!

Answer (score -3):

When it comes to compressing images for your WordPress site, the built-in compression in newer WordPress versions is quite effective and convenient. It automatically optimizes images during the upload process, ensuring a balance between file size and visual quality. However, if you're dealing with a large batch of images, Photoshop and third-party plugins like Shortpixel offer more granular control over compression settings.

Photoshop allows you to adjust the compression percentage, providing a manual approach to find the optimal balance between file size and image quality. Shortpixel, on the other hand, is a specialized image optimization plugin that often employs advanced algorithms for efficient compression.

In summary, while WordPress's built-in compression is sufficient for many users, Photoshop and plugins like Shortpixel offer more customization options, making them beneficial for users with specific preferences or requirements for image compression. If batch processing is a priority, exploring both options and assessing the results may help you determine the most suitable solution for your 5000 images.